# Linker failing to find definition for method that is definitely defined in linked library

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, cmake, linker

In a project I'm working on, I'm running into an issue where I am getting the following error:

```
[ 97%] Linking CXX executable Test_formatters
CMakeFiles/Test_formatters.dir/formatters.cpp.o: In function `FormatterTests::JsonFormattter::test_method()':
formatters.cpp:(.text+0xa9e7): undefined reference to `core::log::make_formatter(core::log::FormatterType)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
core/log/test/CMakeFiles/Test_formatters.dir/build.make:104: recipe for target 'core/log/test/Test_formatters' failed
make[2]: *** [core/log/test/Test_formatters] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:504: recipe for target 'core/log/test/CMakeFiles/Test_formatters.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [core/log/test/CMakeFiles/Test_formatters.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:135: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

for a method that is definitely defined. The function in question is part of a library called distro_core_log_static. Here is the cmake which creates my test target for that library, which is where this error is coming from:

```
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DBOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK) 

set(DEPENDENCIES
    distro_core_log_static
    ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY}
    ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY}
    ${Boost_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY})

# formatters
add_executable(Test_formatters formatters.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Test_formatters PUBLIC ${DEPENDENCIES})
```

What is especially odd is the fact that I am using the supposedly undefined method internally within the log library, and getting no such errors. Here is the directory structure in question:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUdM9.png)

Also, lastly, you can see that the method is declared:

```
namespace core
{
    namespace log
    {
        class Formatter;

        enum class FormatterType
        {
            invalid = -1,
            json

        }; // enum class FormatterType

        // Factory method for log formatters
        Formatter* make_formatter(FormatterType type);

        // Convert the provided FormatterType to a string representation
        std::string formatter_type_to_string(FormatterType type);

        // Convert the provided FormatterType string to a FormatterType
        FormatterType string_to_formatter_type(const std::string& formatter_type_str);

        // String representations
        static constexpr const char* const FORMATTER_INVALID_STR = "invalid";
        static constexpr const char* const JSON_FORMATTER_STR = "json";

    } // namespace log

} // namespace core
```

and defined:

```
#include "FormatterFactory.hpp"

#include "Formatter.hpp"
#include "JsonFormatter.hpp"

using namespace core::log;

// Factory method for log formatters
Formatter* make_formatter(FormatterType type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case FormatterType::json:
        {
            return new JsonFormatter;
        }
        case FormatterType::invalid:
        {
            return nullptr;
        }
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Is your static library built with the same compiler and targeting the same architecture as your project?

Comment: yes, it is built along with the project.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of the `make_formatter` function assumes the namespace resolution will understand you are defining the one declared in `core::log`.

However, this is not the case. While `using namespace` will import identifiers into the current namespace, it does not work the other way. When you define `make_formatter`, this does not get pushed back to the `core::log` namespace just because that identifier exists.

In fact, it will overload it by defining a new function in the global namespace:

```
// This function is NOT implementing the one in the core::log namespace
core::log::Formatter* make_formatter(core::log::FormatterType type)
{
    //...
    return nullptr;
}
```

Demonstration of the problem here: https://godbolt.org/z/4WTW4e1cf

So the linker was not lying. There is no implementation for `core::log::make_formatter`.

Your options are either:

1. Explicitly qualify it:

   ```
   using namespace core::log;

   Formatter* core::log::make_formatter(FormatterType type)
   {
       //...
       return nullptr;
   }
   ```
2. Define it within the correct namespace:

   ```
   namespace core 
   {
       namespace log
       {
           Formatter* core::log::make_formatter(FormatterType type)
           {
               //...
               return nullptr;
           }
       }
   }
   ```