# Why can it recognize class SimplyMaxFlow but can't recognize its constructor function SimplyMaxflow() when i move my code from windows to linux?

Tags: c++, or-tools, max-flow

I set:

```
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/home/liush/zhuyugao/or-tools_Ubuntu-16.04-64bit_v9.2.9972/include:$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
```

In code I have:

```
#include"ortools/graph/max_flow.h"
using namespace operations_research;
```

When I write:

```
SimpleMaxflow max_flow;
```

Command line shows:

```
 ‘SimpleMaxflow’ is not a member of ‘operations_research’; did you mean ‘SimpleMaxFlow’?
```

I think it means it can find the namespace operations_research and class SimpleMaxFlow,but when I write:

```
SimpleMaxFlow max_flow;
```

Command line shows:

```
 undefined reference to `operations_research::SimpleMaxFlow::SimpleMaxFlow()'
```

I have realize the same code in windows,but it didn't work on linux server.
Why this happened and How can I solve it?

Add two example codes:

```
#include"ortools/graph/max_flow.h"
using namespace operations_research;
int main()
{
    operations_research::SimpleMaxflow maxflow;
    return 0;
}
```

it shows:

```
daily_test.cpp:5:23: error: ‘SimpleMaxflow’ is not a member of ‘operations_research’; did you mean ‘SimpleMaxFlow’?
```

```
#include"ortools/graph/max_flow.h"
using namespace operations_research;
int main()
{
    operations_research::SimpleMaxFlow maxflow;
    return 0;
}
```

it shows:

```
undefined reference to `operations_research::SimpleMaxFlow::SimpleMaxFlow()'
```

SimpleMaxFlow is in namespace operations_research,operations_research is in ortools/graph/max_flow.h.As below(Also in https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/v9.2/ortools/graph/max_flow.h):

```
namespace operations_research {
// Forward declaration.
template <typename Graph>
class GenericMaxFlow;
// A simple and efficient max-cost flow interface. This is as fast as
// GenericMaxFlow<ReverseArcStaticGraph>, which is the fastest, but uses
// more memory in order to hide the somewhat involved construction of the
// static graph.
//
// TODO(user): If the need arises, extend this interface to support warm start.
class SimpleMaxFlow {
 public:
  // The constructor takes no size.
  // New node indices will be created lazily by AddArcWithCapacity().
  SimpleMaxFlow();

  // Adds a directed arc with the given capacity from tail to head.
  // * Node indices and capacity must be non-negative (>= 0).
  // * Self-looping and duplicate arcs are supported.
  // * After the method finishes, NumArcs() == the returned ArcIndex + 1.
  ArcIndex AddArcWithCapacity(NodeIndex tail, NodeIndex head,
                              FlowQuantity capacity);

  // Returns the current number of nodes. This is one more than the largest
  // node index seen so far in AddArcWithCapacity().
  NodeIndex NumNodes() const;

  // Returns the current number of arcs in the graph.
  ArcIndex NumArcs() const;

  // Returns user-provided data.
  // The implementation will crash if "arc" is not in [0, NumArcs()).
  NodeIndex Tail(ArcIndex arc) const;
  NodeIndex Head(ArcIndex arc) const;
  FlowQuantity Capacity(ArcIndex arc) const;

  // Solves the problem (finds the maximum flow from the given source to the
  // given sink), and returns the problem status.
  enum Status {
    // Solve() was called and found an optimal solution. Note that OptimalFlow()
    // may be 0 which means that the sink is not reachable from the source.
    OPTIMAL,
    // There is a flow > std::numeric_limits<FlowQuantity>::max(). Note that in
    // this case, the class will contain a solution with a flow reaching that
    // bound.
    //
    // TODO(user): rename POSSIBLE_OVERFLOW to INT_OVERFLOW and modify our
    // clients.
    POSSIBLE_OVERFLOW,
    // The input is inconsistent (bad tail/head/capacity values).
    BAD_INPUT,
    // This should not happen. There was an error in our code (i.e. file a bug).
    BAD_RESULT
  };
  Status Solve(NodeIndex source, NodeIndex sink);

  // Returns the maximum flow we can send from the source to the sink in the
  // last OPTIMAL Solve() context.
  FlowQuantity OptimalFlow() const;

  // Returns the flow on the given arc in the last OPTIMAL Solve() context.
  //
  // Note: It is possible that there is more than one optimal solution. The
  // algorithm is deterministic so it will always return the same solution for
  // a given problem. However, there is no guarantee of this from one code
  // version to the next (but the code does not change often).
  FlowQuantity Flow(ArcIndex arc) const;

  // Returns the nodes reachable from the source by non-saturated arcs (.i.e.
  // arc with Flow(arc) < Capacity(arc)), the outgoing arcs of this set form a
  // minimum cut. This works only if Solve() returned OPTIMAL.
  void GetSourceSideMinCut(std::vector<NodeIndex>* result);

  // Returns the nodes that can reach the sink by non-saturated arcs, the
  // outgoing arcs of this set form a minimum cut. Note that if this is the
  // complement set of GetNodeReachableFromSource(), then the min-cut is unique.
  // This works only if Solve() returned OPTIMAL.
  void GetSinkSideMinCut(std::vector<NodeIndex>* result);

  // Change the capacity of an arc.
  //
  // WARNING: This looks like it enables incremental solves, but as of 2018-02,
  // the next Solve() will restart from scratch anyway.
  // TODO(user): Support incrementality in the max flow implementation.
  void SetArcCapacity(ArcIndex arc, FlowQuantity capacity);

  // Creates the protocol buffer representation of the current problem.
  FlowModelProto CreateFlowModelProto(NodeIndex source, NodeIndex sink) const;

 private:
  NodeIndex num_nodes_;
  std::vector<NodeIndex> arc_tail_;
  std::vector<NodeIndex> arc_head_;
  std::vector<FlowQuantity> arc_capacity_;
  std::vector<ArcIndex> arc_permutation_;
  std::vector<FlowQuantity> arc_flow_;
  FlowQuantity optimal_flow_;

  // Note that we cannot free the graph before we stop using the max-flow
  // instance that uses it.
  typedef ::util::ReverseArcStaticGraph<NodeIndex, ArcIndex> Graph;
  std::unique_ptr<Graph> underlying_graph_;
  std::unique_ptr<GenericMaxFlow<Graph> > underlying_max_flow_;

  DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(SimpleMaxFlow);
};
```

Comment: You are not showing enough code to elicit an answer. My crystal ball tells me that you did not fully-qualify the _definition_ of `SimpleMaxFlow`'s methods or define them within the correct namespace. Instead, so the crystal ball tells me, you relied on `using namespace` to automatically attach your unqualified definition to the declaration in the imported namespace. I saw a [similar situation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73132074/1553090) yesterday.

Comment: Ok,I add two example codes

Comment: Is `SimpleMaxFlow` a class that you wrote yourself? Or is it part of a library? If the latter, are you _linking_ to that library? Still there is not enough code here to answer. You have shown how you're attempting to use the class, but you haven't shown how the class is defined.

Comment: The code snippets in the question don't have a definition for what seems to be a namespace named `operations_research`, much less any indication of what its contents might be, so error messages about its contents are meaningless. Post real code.

Comment: Don't supplement your question in comments. Rewrite the question so that it explains what's what.